# Force Gmail for iPhone to render table cells at their designated widths?

Tags: html, iphone, css, email, gmail

Table cell widths are staggered in iPhone Gmail.

Is there a way to force Gmail for iPhone to render table cells at their designated widths? Oddly, the multi-slice rows expand to the set 'width:650'. The single slice rows are narrower although they are also set to 'width:650'.

As far as I can tell, my emails look perfect in all desktop email clients - even Outlook! It also looks fine in Mail for iPhone.

I've tried using 'border-collapse:collapse', 'width:100%' on the tables and td's, and finally 'table-layout:fixed'.

This is the HTML:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title>
</head>
<body>
<img border="0" style="display:block;" src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" />
<table bgcolor="#fff" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:650px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <!--/*************** BEGIN LEAD ***************/ -->
            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff"  width="650"><a href="" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#040400; text-decoration:underline;line-height:20px;"><span id="part1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></a></td>
            <!-- /*************** END LEAD ***************/ --> 
        </tr>
        <!-- /*************** BEGIN HEADER INC ***************/ -->
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff"  width="650"><table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#666; line-height:13px;margin-top:2px;"><a style="color:#666; text-decoration:underline;line-height:13px;" href="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a><a href="" style="color:#666; font-size:10px; text-decoration:underline;line-height:13px;"></a> iXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<a style="color:#666; text-decoration:underline;font-size:10px;line-height:13px;" href=""> XXXXXXXXXXXX</a>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br />
                            <span style="font-weight:bold;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><img src="spacer.gif" width="650" height="46" border="0" style="display: block;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Table_01" width="650" height="47" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="280"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_01.gif" width="280" height="47" alt="Territory Ahead"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="370"><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_02.gif" width="370" height="47" alt=""></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Table_01" width="650" height="31" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="97"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_03.gif" width="97" height="31" alt="Men's"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="90"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_04.gif" width="90" height="31" alt="Women's"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="93"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_05.gif" width="93" height="31" alt="Isabella Bird"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="132"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_06.gif" width="132" height="31" alt="Men's Clearance"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="83"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_07.gif" width="83" height="31" alt="Women's Clearance"> </a></td>
                                    <td width="155"><a href=""> <img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer3_08.gif" width="155" height="31" alt="eGift Cards"> </a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border-top: solid 1px #b69358;" width="650">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="650" style="height:8px;" ></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /*************** END HEADER INC ***************/ --> 
        <!-- /*************** BEGIN PROMO ***************/ --> 
        <!-- /*************** END PROMO ***************/ -->
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff"  width="650"><!-- /*************** BEGIN MAIN ***************/ -->

                <table id="Table_01" width="650" height="1595" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_01.gif" width="650" height="352" alt=""></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_02.jpg" width="650" height="405" alt=""></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_03.jpg" width="650" height="408" alt=""></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="650"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_04.jpg" width="650" height="430" alt=""></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <!-- /*************** END MAIN ***************/ --></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /*************** BEGIN FOOTER INC ***************/ -->
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff"  width="650"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650"><table id="Table_01" width="650" height="32" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="125"><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_01.gif" width="125" height="32" alt=""></td>
                                            <td width="88"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_02.gif" width="88" height="32" alt=""></a></td>
                                            <td width="158"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_03.gif" width="158" height="32" alt=""></a></td>
                                            <td width="105"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;" src="spacer_04.gif" width="105" height="32" alt=""></a></td>
                                            <td width="31"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_05.gif" width="31" height="32" alt=""></a></td>
                                            <td width="31"><a href=""><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_06.gif" width="31" height="32" alt=""></a></td>
                                            <td width="112"><img border="0" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" src="spacer_07.gif" width="112" height="32" alt=""></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px;" width="650"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10px;color:#666; line-height:13px;"><a style="font-size:10px;color:#666; text-decoration:none;" href="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a> | <a style="font-size:10px; color:#666; text-decoration:none;" href="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a><br />
                                <br />
                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br />
                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br />
                                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="650"><span style="font-family: Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#000;"><img src="spacer.gif" width="650" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;margin:0;padding:0;"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /*************** END FOOTER INC ***************/ --> 
        <!-- /*************** BEGIN DISC ***************/ -->
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff"  width="650"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#000;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /*************** END DISC ***************/ -->
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution!  For an image to render at full width in the Gmail mobile app, the `img` tag must contain the style property set to `style="display:block;min-width:650px;`. This forces the content to full width as the Gmail mobile app is programmed to 'auto-adjust' the size of elements within the email. Thanks for your help on this Jon!

Comment: After an hour of trying various method, this did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @lifwanian! I discovered this accidentally, after it was recommended to try 'min-width' in the parent 'td' element which had no effect.

Comment: Had this exact same problem, that min-width did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the sliced rows, you don't have `width=""` set in your `<td>` tags. I know it is in the image tags, but it might make a difference.

Also try using `style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"` on your images, it may help.

Try those 2 things - if they don't help, update and re-post the code so we can eliminate those potential issues. A screenshot/image of the error might also help.

Comment: Thanks John. I will try that. Here's a link to a snapshot of the sample code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rn7318owfwjuzwf/QA-stackOverflow-iPhoneGmail.jpg

Comment: So which part is wrong? the main image(s) of the woman and title menu bar, or the header and footers (hanging clothes) that appears not as wide? Did you add the table cell widths as suggested?

Comment: The navigation bar and the images of the woman are right, they are also multiple slices and set at 'width:650'. The maroon promo block and the hanging clothes block are wrong, they are also one slice each set at 'width:650'. I added the table cell widths but do not have an iPhone Gmail app testing environment so will have to wait for email to be deployed to see the results.

Comment: John, setting the widths to every <td> and using style="margin:0;padding:0;display:block;" on the images did not make a difference. I have uploaded new desktop Gmail and iPhone 4S Gmail app snapshots to give you a clear picture.

Comment: Email snapshot: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mqofbh6nsu93j6w/45HIUrgmAm). The horizontal line under the nav buttons extend the whole width of the email unlike the main body in red (650px).